# Why do I get the error "The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat" when I use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

Tags: android, material-components-android

I use Android Studio wizard *"Empty Compose Activity"* just like Image A to create a blank project just Code A, and I add a function `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` to hope to show a dialog.

But I get the error *"The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat"*, you can see the details at Result A.

What's wrong with my code?

**Image A**
[image]

**Code A**

```
MainActivity.kt

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
import info.dodata.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
    val singleItems = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
    val checkedItem = 1

    val context = LocalContext.current

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setNeutralButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
        }
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
        }
        .setSingleChoiceItems(singleItems, checkedItem) { dialog, which ->

        }
        .show()
}




build.gradle
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

**Result A**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:241)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:211)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:146)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:75)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialDialogs.getDialogBackgroundInsets(MaterialDialogs.java:60)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.<init>(MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java:117)
        at com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.<init>(MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java:103)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.MainActivityKt.Greeting(MainActivity.kt:42)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:27)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$6.invoke(Surface.kt:268)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$6.invoke(Surface.kt:255)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:252)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:110)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:21)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme_androidKt.PlatformMaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.android.kt:23)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:82)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:265)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ui.theme.ThemeKt.MyApplicationTheme(Theme.kt:41)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:21)
        at info.dodata.myapplication.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:20)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
2022-07-20 11:07:05.231 27136-27136/info.dodata.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
```

Comment: So what theme have you set in the `android:theme` in your AndroidManifest.xml? Why are you even using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` in a Compose app when you can use the [Compose Material `AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties)) directly?

Comment: Thanks!  The code above is from  https://material.io/components/dialogs#confirmation-dialog , I was told that the code can be used in Compose